# Filtering out all but one result per group out of similar results

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table that lists all the `prime_ministers` and what `year` they served and what `party` they were in.

I need the 3 bits of information; Their `name`, their first `year` of office and `party` in their final year of office (some switched parties).

The table looks a bit like this

```
min_nr|pm_name      |party           |yr_comm  
---------------------------------------------- 
1      Barton E      Protectionist    1901  
.  
.  
.  
11     Hughes W M    Labour           1915  
12     Hughes W M    National Labour  1916  
13     Hughes W M    Nationalists     1917  
14     Hughes W M    Nationalists     1918  
.  
.
```

I have done lots of searches but I don't know how to type this in to get a result.

Mr Woo did it in the comments section. It turns out I dont understand multiple JOINS and the correct usage of AND in ON.

```
SELECT a.pm_name, a.party, c.minYear
FROM  Table1 a 
      INNER JOIN
      (
          SELECT pm_name, MAX(yr_comm) maxYear
          FROM table1
          GROUP BY pm_name
      ) b ON a.pm_name = b.pm_name AND
             a.yr_comm = b.maxYear
      INNER JOIN
      (
        SELECT pm_name, MIN(yr_comm) minYear
        FROM table1
        GROUP BY  pm_name
      ) c ON a.pm_name = c.Pm_name
```

*Edits, many many edits*

Comment: so in your updated question, what will be the result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try a subquery to get the maximum year for each prime minister. This works if you want to get all columns.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM tableName a INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT ID, MAX(`year`) maxYear
            FROM tableName
            GROUP BY ID
        ) b ON a.ID = b.ID AND
                a.`Year` = b.maxYear
```

`tableName` => change it to the name of your table 
`ID` => change it to the primary key 
`Year` => change it to the column name for your year.

but if you onlyu want to get the `ID` of the prime minister and what year is their final year. You can do it directly without subquery.

```
SELECT ID, MAX(`year`) finalYear
FROM tableName
GROUP BY ID
```

***PS: if this answer is still not clear, please add the schema of your table, sample records, and desired result and we can work on it. Thanks.***

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT a.pm_name, a.party, c.minYear
FROM  Table1 a 
      INNER JOIN
      (
          SELECT pm_name, MAX(yr_comm) maxYear
          FROM table1
          GROUP BY pm_name
      ) b ON a.pm_name = b.pm_name AND
             a.yr_comm = b.maxYear
      INNER JOIN
      (
        SELECT pm_name, MIN(yr_comm) minYear
        FROM table1
        GROUP BY  pm_name
      ) c ON a.pm_name = c.Pm_name
```

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3e787/7)

Comment: OK, what you said didn't quite work, but with some googling bits of your code and modifying it, I can finally see a way for it to work. Im going to retype my question to be more useful to other people.

Comment: @Talisin so in your updated question, what will be the result?

Comment: pm_name, first year of office, party of last year of office.

Comment: OH right, for the part of the table i have shown it would be Barton E, Protectionist, 1901 and Hughes W M, Nationalists, 1915. The trouble im having is that nationalists is supposed to represent the last Huges W M entery, and 1915 the fist.

Comment: @Talisin is this what you are looking for? [click this link for demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e3e787/7)

Comment: Wow, thanks that is exactly it. Ok, Im gonna hit the books and start trying to understand joins better. Thank you so much for your time and help.